# How to create an FB app without a secure canvas URL

Tags: https, facebook-canvas

I have a simple app I want to create, which allows you to place any website within your Facebook page on a tab.

Previously, I could just do this without a secure canvas URL, but now it is telling me that I must have this to create the app.

Is there a way around this, as the app does not take any info from anybody, it just shows a site from my server on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. You do not need to provide an encrypted connection if the app runs in sandbox mode but otherwise it is mandatory.

Well, actually people using secure browsing will just see an error message at the moment but judging from recent announcements apps without an encrypted connection will be blocked a bit further down the road.